# Ubuntu Software is not installing or updating anything. (16.04.1)

Tags: 16.04

When I try to install something via a `.deb` file or just from software center it will say installing for a second or so then go back to the button saying install. When I try to update the software I have installed it just shows the installing sign but doesn't update, I left it running over night but still nothing updated

Picture of me trying to update:
[image]

Comment: You should have 16.04.2 by now. That means you haven't installed any updates lately. Please do it before anything else: `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`. The try again, it **should** work now. Alternatively install GDebi (by command line) and/or simply install in command line with `dpkg`.

Comment: Doesn't Work it comes up with this message. http://pastebin.com/ZqJXkVc4 (too long to paste directly)

Comment: You have dependency problems that are preventing the installation of other software including all the updates you need. And the problem is with the `wine-devel` package that somehow you tried to install, most likely by following some outdated guide/tutorial. It's all mentioned in the error messages you apparently didn't bother reading. The problem with the Ubuntu Software is just a (quite obvious) symptom.

Comment: Thank you for the help, and sorry for my incompetence, I'm fairly new to Ubuntu so I don't know about trouble shooting in terminal but managed to solve the problem and update my system and now the store works. Next time I'll make sure I update my systems. (BTW I did read it I just didn't understand it)

Comment: Ubuntu Software Center is also heavy and sometimes buggy. I think that you'd better use the command line for updating and installing, it is faster and more reliable. it is a good habit to take, in my opinion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, fix your dependencies. To do this, open a terminal and enter this command:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

After that, update your software:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Don't use the application `Ubuntu Software`. The scientific term for it is "complete and utter garbage with tons of bugs which doesn't work 90% of the time and shouldn't be used by anyone for any purpose whatsoever". If you want to use a graphical interface, use `Ubuntu Software Center`. You can install it with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

It's a bit slower but it works and gets the job done.

If you want to install a Debian package, you can either open it with `Ubuntu Software Center` or you can install it on the command line (assuming the package is in your downloads folder):

```
sudo apt-get install ~/Downloads/thepackage.deb
```

Note that you probably can install the Debian package directly from the repos without first downloading it. If your Debian package is called `Awesome-Application_1.37_amd64.deb`, try this command:

```
sudo apt-get install awesome-application
```

It either finds something with that name or tells you that it can't find it. In the latter case, execute the command mentioned two above to install the package you downloaded.

Comment: A simple `sudo apt install -f` suffices for me.

Answer (score -1):

In Ubuntu 16 I highly recommend installing GDebi package installer from the Ubuntu Software Center. Then open any downloaded .deb files with that. It will automatically install dependencies.

Comment: That won't fix the current dependency issues though. -1